# Grid-Search finding Parameters for AUC

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search

I'm trying to find the parameters for my SVM, which give me the best AUC. But i can't find any scoring function for AUC in sklearn. Does someone have an idea? Here is my Code:

```
    parameters = {"C":[0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], "gamma":[0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]}
    clf = SVC(kernel = "rbf")
    clf = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring = ???)
    svr.fit(features_train , labels_train)
    print svr.best_params_
```

So what can i use for ??? to get the best parameters for an high AUC score?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Comment: so if i print out svr.best_score_ its the auc? because i tried to compute it like this: `#ROC
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(labels_test, labels_predicted)
roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
print roc_auc` but it shows me a lower auc than the best score

Comment: The best score corresponds to the best average `roc_auc` over each of the folds in the training process. One would expect to see a lower score on a test set.

Answer (score 11):

You can make any scorer by your own:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

# define scoring function 
 def custom_auc(ground_truth, predictions):
     # I need only one column of predictions["0" and "1"]. You can get an error here
     # while trying to return both columns at once
     fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(ground_truth, predictions[:, 1], pos_label=1)    
     return auc(fpr, tpr)

# to be standart sklearn's scorer        
 my_auc = make_scorer(custom_auc, greater_is_better=True, needs_proba=True)

 pipeline = Pipeline(
                [("transformer", TruncatedSVD(n_components=70)),
                ("classifier", xgb.XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=1.0, learning_rate=0.1, 
                                max_depth=5, n_estimators=50, min_child_weight=5))])

 parameters_grid = {'transformer__n_components': [60, 40, 20] }

 grid_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters_grid, scoring = my_auc, n_jobs=-1,
                                                        cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5,test_size=0.3,random_state = 0))
 grid_cv.fit(X, y)
```

For more information, please check out here: [sklearn make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html)

Answer (score 6):

use  below code which will give you all the list of parameter

```
import sklearn

sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()
```

Select appropriate parameter that you want to use

In your case below code will work

```
clf = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring = 'roc_auc')
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but I believe you want to use the `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score`.

The problem is that it's not a model scorer, so you need to build one.
Something like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

def score_auc(estimator, X, y):
    y_score = estimator.predict_proba(X)  # You could also use the binary predict, but probabilities should give you a more realistic score.
    return roc_auc_score(y, y_score)
```

and use this function as scoring parameter in the GridSearch.

Comment: thanks, i like your idea but if i do this: `svr = GridSearchCV(svr, parameters, scoring = score_auc(svr, features_train, labels_train))`it causes: AttributeError: predict_proba is not available when  probability=False. If i set it on true another error shows up.

Comment: just do a `svr = GridSearchCV(svr, parameters, scoring=score_auc)`, you shouldn't call the function, just pass it to the search. If the `predict_proba` is giving you problems, just score with the regular `predict`.

Comment: It feels like this will pass "score_auc" the train data - what if we want to score it on the cross validation data as we go along?

Comment: For some SVM models, you need to explicitly set the hyperparameter "probability=True" when initializing them, in order to get probabilistic predictions.