# How to set AUC as scoring method while searching for hyperparameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to perform a random search, in classification problem, where the scoring method will be chosen as AUC instead of accuracy score. Have a look at my code for reproducibility:

```
# Define imports and create data 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.binomial(0, 1, 100)


### Let's define parameter grid

rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)

n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start=200, stop=2000, num=4)]
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
param_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split}


# Define model
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, 
                         param_grid, 
                         random_state=0, 
                         n_iter=3, 
                         cv=5).fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y)
```

And now, according to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) of function `RandomizedSearchCV` I can pass another argument `scoring` which will choose metric to evaluate the model. I tried to pass `scoring = auc`, but I got an error that there is no such metric. Do you know what I have to do to have AUC instead of accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation of function RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) scoring can be a string or a callable. [Here you can find](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) all possible string values for the score parameter. You can also try to set score as a callable [auc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html#sklearn.metrics.auc).

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Danylo and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689942/grid-search-finding-parameters-for-auc) you can specify the search optimal function to be the ROC-AUC, so as to pick the parameter value maximizing it:

```py
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, 
                         param_grid, 
                         random_state=0, 
                         n_iter=3, 
                         cv=5,
                         scoring='roc_auc').fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y)
```